# Delete Rows from multiple tables using Linq web Api asp.net

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, cascade, http-delete

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteUser(string id)
        {
            try {
                using (hospiceEntities db = new hospiceEntities())
                {
                    Guid guid_id = Guid.Parse(id);
                    var q =
                    (from user in db.Users
                     join resource in db.Resources
                     on user.Id equals resource.UserId
                     where user.Id == guid_id
                     select user).Single<User>();

                    foreach (Resource res in q.Resources)
                    {
                        db.Resources.Remove(res);

                    }
                    db.Users.Remove(q);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return Ok(Helper.SuccessResponse("User Deleted"));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I have two tables **Users** and **Resource** that are connected through foreign key constraint. I have written the above LINQ query to delete the record but its not deleting it. Please tell what i am doing wrong in it. Thanks

Comment: Is there any exception you get?

Comment: Did you debug your code? Did you check if you are getting any value in `q` or in `q.Resources`?

Comment: the exception i get is " "Message": "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." status 400 badrequest

Comment: in q.Resources i am getting all the data of both tables. it works fine till the foreach loop but after moving out of loop it doesnot execute the next statement but jumps to the catch block.

Comment: How about if you try with `ToList` e.g `foreach (Resource res in q.Resources.ToList())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this way:

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteUser(string id)
        {
            try {
                using (hospiceEntities db = new hospiceEntities())
                {
                    Guid guid_id = Guid.Parse(id);
                    var deleteuser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == guid_id);
                    if (deleteuser == null)
                    {
                        return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "User Not Found");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var q =
                    from user in db.Users
                    join resource in db.Resources
                    on user.Id equals resource.UserId
                    where user.Id == guid_id
                    select new
                    {
                        Users = user,
                        Resources = resource
                    };
                        foreach (var item in q)
                        {
                            db.Resources.Remove(item.Resources);
                            db.Users.Remove(item.Users);
                        }
                        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                }
                return Ok(Helper.SuccessResponse("User Deleted"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include resources using this syntax

```
    var user = await
    db.Users
   .Include(u=>u.Resources)
   .Where(u=> u.Id == guid_id)
   .FirstOrDefaltAsync();

   var res=user.Resources.ToList();
     db.Resources.RemoveRange(res);

    // or try directly
   db.Resources.RemoveRange(user.Resourses);

  //or maybe this is better
     user.Resources==null;
     
     db.Users.Remove(user);
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in foreach loop

```
(db.GetTable<Resource>().DeleteOnSubmit(res));
```

and use this code

```
db.GetTable<Users>().DeleteOnSubmit(q);  
                    db.SubmitChanges();
```

instead of `(db.Users.Remove(q));`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).